# How to print only hidden files in a directory using the 'ls' cmd?

Tags: c, unix, ls

I am trying to read a path from the cmd line and then run the 'ls' cmd to print only the hidden files and their long information in the path specified, and then to a text file. My problem is that 'ls' returns:

ls: illegal option --

ls: illegal option -- .

ls: illegal option -- ?

ls: illegal option -- *

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUMARG 2


/* start main */
  int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

/* define data */
DIR *dirptr;
struct dirent *dp;
int pid;
    int fd = open("output_file", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666);

 /* Command Line Check */
 if(argc != NUMARG){
  fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s dirname\n", argv[0]);
  exit(1);
  }

  /* Open the specified directory */
 if((dirptr = opendir(argv[1])) == NULL){
  fprintf(stderr, "Could not open directory %s\n", argv[1]);
   exit(1);
    }

/* fork another process */
  switch(pid = fork()){

   /* succesfull child process */
   case 0:
         dup2(fd, 1);
         close(fd);
         printf("Running ls\n");
         execlp( "ls", "ls" , "-ld .?*", argv[1], (char*)NULL);
         perror("execlp");
         exit(1);
       default:
         sleep(5);
         printf("Hitting default...\n");
         break;
      case -1:
         perror("err");
         exit(1);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, May I ask why you are forking?

Comment: Ok, I got it after reading the doc from execlp ^^

Comment: Trying to print the output of ls -ld .?* to a text file.

Comment: each word should be a separate argument...

Comment: I did this: execlp( "ls", "ls" , "-ld" , ".?*", argv[1], (char*)NULL);
and get error: .?*: No such file or directory

Comment: Wildcard substitution is done by the shell, not by the `exec` functions. You can use `system` instead to run the shell.

Answer (score 2):

Run `ls` through a shell

```
execlp("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", "ls -l .?*", (char *) NULL);
```

that way you get access to shell wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

did you try splitting the args like that:

```
 execlp( "ls", "ls" , "-ld", ".?*", argv[1], (char*)NULL); // does not work due to ".?*" has to be expanded by bash
```

Use `find` instead of ls:

```
execlp( "find", "find", argv[1], "-maxdepth", "1", "-name", ".?*", (char*)NULL);
```

Comment: Yes and that doesn't work for me:

.?*: No such file or directory

Comment: did you try adding -a option. This will also list hidden files, which '.*' files are

Comment: @totoro is right, the expansion of the wildcard is done by bash, not by ls. Another solution can be to use the 'find' cmd which supports wildcard internally:  find <from_folder> -name '.*' 
Be aware that 'fins' searches from <from_folder> and all its subfolders.The -maxdepth option can limit this...

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '.?*'`

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint: here's one possible sample - this part of code should do the listing of invisible files from the current directory...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char s [256] ;
  strcat(s, "ls -ld .?*");
  system(s);
  return 0;
}
```